# Execute query lazily in Orient-DB

Tags: lazy-evaluation, orientdb, graph-databases, graph-traversal, orient-sql

In current project we need to find cheapest paths in almost fully connected graph which can contain lots of edges per vertex pair.

We developed [a plugin](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Extend-Server.html) containing functions

1. for special traversal this graph to lower reoccurences of similar paths while `TRAVERSE` execution. We will refer it as `search()`
2. for special effective extraction of desired information from results of such traverses. We will refer it as `extract()`
3. for extracting best `N` records according to target parameter without costly `ORDER BY`. We will refer it as `best()`

But resulted query still has unsatisfactory performance on full data.

So we decided to modify `search()` function so it could watch best edges first and prune paths leading to definitely undesired result by using current state of `best()` function.
Overall solution is effectively a flexible implementation of [Branch and Bound method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound)

Resulting query (omitting `extract()` step) should look like

```
SELECT best(path, <limit>) FROM (
   TRAVERSE search(<params>) FROM #<starting_point>
   WHILE <conditions on intermediate vertixes>
  ) WHERE <conditions on result elements>
```

This form is very desired so we could adapt conditions under `WHILE` and `WHERE` for our current task. The `path` field is generated by `search()` containing all information for `best()` to proceed.

The trouble is that `best()` function is executed strictly after `search()` function, so `search()` can not prune non-optimal branches according to results already evaluated by `best()`.

So the Question is:
Is there a way to pipeline results from `TRAVERSE` step to `SELECT` step in the way that older paths were `TRAVERSE`d with `search()` after earlier paths handled by `SELECT` with `best()`?

Comment: are you using v2.1.6?

Comment: @Lvca I believe it's 2.1.0 Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query execution in this case will be streamed. If you add a

```
 System.out.println()
```

or you put a breakpoint in your functions you'll see that the invocation sequence will be

```
search
best
search
best
search
...
```

You can use a ThreadLocal object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

to store some context data and share it between the two functions, or you can use the OCommandContext (the last parameter in `OSQLFunction.execute()` method to store context information.

You can use `context.getVariable()` and `context.setVariable()` for this.

The contexts of the two queries (the parent and the inner query) are different, but they should be linked by a parent/child relationship, so you should be able to retrieve them using `OCommandContext.getParent()`

Comment: It's big old trouble but `iContext` seems to be `null` inside the traversed function (referred as `search`). But it's seems working on very simple test functions, and not confirmed at target ones.

Question was created because I have wrong ensurance that `TRAVERSE` and `SELECT` has similar behaviour. And in chained `SELECT` such streaming definitely did not occur.

I'll verify streaming in couple days and award bounty then

Comment: if context is null is a bug. Could you try with 2.1.6?